# Get id from row listview

Tags: android, listview

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long rid) {

                lv.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext(), RestaurantActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("restaurant_id", restid);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

`lv.getAdapter().getItem(position)` GIVES ME

```
{number_of_orders=1 offer, restaurant_id=5, distance=5.0 km, restaurantname=Brookside}
```

I want only restaurant_id value, i.e. 5.

So, how to get id from row **listview** (id is populated via mysql json response) android
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line:

```
lv.getAdapter().getItem(position)
```

returns you an `Object` which its type is the same as the one that you have given to your `Adapter`. For example with this adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<MyObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyObject>(...);
```

The object collected will be a `MyObject`.

So if you want to get only the `restaurant_id` you just have to add a getter in your `MyObject` class which returns the id:

```
public class MyObject {
    private int id;
    ...
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then when you want to get this id you can do like this:

```
MyObject myObject = (MyObject) lv.getAdapter().getItem(position);
int id = myObject.getId();
```

Comment: Brilliant. What a precise conceptual explanation you have given :). I was using a HashMap<String, String>. So this is what i did. 
 HashMap<String, String> myObject = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    String id = myObject.get(String.valueOf("restaurant_id"));

AND woala...i got my ID. :)